# Python - List Iteration Error

Tags: python

I am developing a Python Twitch IRC Bot with a currency system. Every minute, I add one point to the user's "balance." However, I am getting a `TypeError` in my console whenever I run the script. It says `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, and I have no clue how to fix it, and I have no idea what the problem is as it was working perfectly fine earlier. Here's my code:

```
userlist = [open('userlist.txt').read()]
balances = [open('balances.txt').read()]

def loadusers():
    global userlist
    userlist = [map(str, userlist[0].split(", "))]
def loadbalances():
    global balances
    balances = [map(int, balances[0].split(", "))]
def savelist(path, listname):
    with open(path, 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write(re.sub('[\'\[\]]', '', str(listname)))

loadusers()
loadbalances()

def givePoints():
    num = 0
    for users in balances:
        balances[num] += 1
        num += 1
    threading.Timer(60.0, givePoints).start()
```

I am getting the error on the line that says `balances[num] += 1`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't see how you'd get exactly the error you describe. I'd expect some other issue (like an `IndexError`) since you're making a bunch of really odd lists. Don't just randomly square brackets around anything for the heck of it! Anyway, are you sure you're getting the `TypeError` you describe with the code you've shown?

Comment: map() returns a map object, so `balances` is assigned a list containing one map object (which you can't add 1 to).  Change it to `balances = list(map(int, balances[0].split(", "))), and it seems to work.  At least `balances[num]` will be an integer, like you're expecting (I think).

Comment: @jfsturtz In python 2, `map` returns a list.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you for saying that, I removed the brackets around my `map` line and now it works perfectly!

Comment: You should answer your own question with the explanation you added so that people can see your problem is solved.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for reminding me.  I've only worked in Python 3, so I'm not very up on 2 vs. 3 differences.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I removed the brackets from around my `[map(str, userlist[0].split(", "))]` statement, and now it works perfectly! Thanks to everybody's tips :)